# git commit -a --file message.txt; git format-patch removes newlines from message.txt

Tags: git

When using a text file for a commit message `git commit -a --file message.txt` and then generating a patch file with `git format-patch` the commit message get written with all newlines stripped (Linux).

Seems like the culprit is the `format-patch`

> By default, the subject of a single patch is "[PATCH] " followed by
>   the concatenation of lines from the commit message up to the first
>   blank line (see the DISCUSSION section of git-commit[1]).

I could not find yet the way to change this default behaviour. Is there a way?

How can I change it to take the commit message verbatim from the `message.txt` and put it into the generated 0001-xxx.patch file?

so from

```
* change 1
* change 2
```

it goes to

```
* change 1 * change 2
```

when running `git format-patch` and I obviously want it to keep the newlines.

This is how I am checking the result:

```
less message.txt
git commit -a --file message.txt
git format-patch -1 my_branch
less *.patch
```

To clarify and confirm, the `git show` shows the commit message with intact newlines. I am using Linux term.

EDIT: rewritten the question to reflect the format-patch at the core of the problem

EDIT2: I have found a workaround: in case there is an empty line after the first line in the message.txt the rest of the file format is preserved.

So this is how I have to format the message.txt

```
 first line 
 empty line
 * change 1
 * change 2
```

With this I have solved my immediate problem but not sure if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: What line ending characters are present in `message.txt`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behavior; in my tests, the newlines are preserved. Can you clarify what command or tool you're using to look at the commit message, just to make sure that isn't a factor in what is observed?

Comment: I just use 
git format-patch -1 my_branch_name;
less *.patch

Comment: @mkrieger1 - not sure how to double check on your question but the message.txt was created on Linux and I am using git on the same Linux machine. So I would assume it is the UNIX line ending.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I have edited my question to add the information you requested

Comment: I just tried `git format-patch -1 --keep-subject`. It produced a long Subject line with quoted-printable encoded newlines. Unfortunately, `git am` does not reproduce the original lines, but turns the Subject line into a single line.

Comment: The lines above the first non-leading blank line are considered as the subject. And the rest lines below are the body. The leading blank lines are stripped. Usually there is only one line for the subject and one or more lines for the body. The newlines in the subject are replaced with spaces in commands like `git log --pretty=%s` and `git format-patch` where the subject is formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git doesn't offer an option to change this.  `git format-patch` needs a subject for the patches it formats, since they are essentially email messages.  As such, it has to assume some format for the commit messages.

The standard Git format for commit message is that there is a short summary on the first line, a blank line, and then an optional (but recommended) longer description, optionally with trailers separated by a blank line.  There are many, many tools, including parts of Git, that assume this format, and I highly recommend that you follow it.

The "by default" text you mentioned above means that you can use the `--subject-prefix` option to customize the `[PATCH]` portion of the message, not the selection of the subject portion of the email.

Comment: just to confirm - as I have added an empty line after the first (subject) line the rest of the message was indeed formatted "as is" by format-patch

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option "-k" for both "git format-patch" and "git am" commands.

For example:

```
  git format-patch master^..master -k 
  git am -k XXX.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use commit templates.

I don't know if that suitable for you since you might need a different message per commit **but still useful if not others can benefit from that as well**.

## `git commit.template`

- create a commit template file with your content

  ```
  # set the commit template in your global git config
  git config --global commit.template <.git-commit-template.txt file path>
  ```
- Now your `~/.gitconfig` should contain:

  ```
  [commit]
      template = <.git-commit-template.txt file path>
  ```
- If you wish to use empty commit

  ```
  # If you allow empty commit messages set
  git config --global commit.cleanup strip
  ```

> **`--cleanup=<mode>`**
>
> This option sets how the commit message is cleaned up.
>   The `<mode>` can be one of `verbatim`, `whitespace`, `strip`, and `default`.
>
> The **`default`** mode will strip leading and trailing empty lines and #commentary from the commit message only if the message is to be edited. Otherwise only whitespace removed.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mode         | Description                                      |
---------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| verbatim     | does not change message at all,                  |
| whitespace   | removes just leading/trailing whitespace lines   |
| strip        | removes both whitespace and commentary.          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! Not sure if this is relevant at all because the problem is with the git format-patch. 'git show' shows proper newlines. I have edited my question to clarify on that since your answer was posted.